# How to detect object by color with openCV

Tags: c#, opencv

I have to make a macros, it should detect object by color on the certain area on the picture of the screen. Further, I need to continue execute code if object has been detected.

```
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgWindowScreen;
    Image<Gray, Byte> imgWindowScreenProcessed;
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
    System.Drawing.Graphics gfxScreenshot;
    Size size = new Size(400, 120);

bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(700, 347, 0, 0, size);

imgWindowScreen = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmpScreenshot);

imgWindowScreenProcessed = imgWindowScreen.InRange(new Bgr(3, 25, 82),
                                         new Bgr(50, 98, 200));
```

Is it right I have choosen the area? I have a upper left point and I need to get something like that:
[image]

How to define that imgWindowScreenProcessed has a pixels of searched color? I need to build a following structure:

```
if (picture has pixels of searched color) {...}
else {...}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you only need to detect the object of a specific color?

Comment: @БолатТлеубаев  I need to detect color and then, if color has been detected, I need do something

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) you may find the Python implementation of HSV thresholding. I understand that you need it on another language, however you might get some insights on logic of the implementation as it shows a simple case. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) you can find a deeper C++ implementation

After you have obtained the binary image, where pixels of desired color are 1 and other pixels are 0, you may play with morphology to enhance the image [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html), and get proper regions of interest.

Then, when you have an in image you may want to see the location of the object. You may use [findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) function to get the location of the object.

I usually do work with OpenCV in Python, but hope that this may also be helpful! :)